# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared_preferences:lintClassPath'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

When I tried to add shared_preferences package i got this error

**Error**

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences:extractDebugAnnotations'.
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared_preferences:lintClassPath'.
>   Could not find kotlin-compiler-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:27.1.0).
>   Searched in the following locations:
>   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/27.1.0/kotlin-compiler-27.1.0.jar
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 31s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
> exit code 1 Exited (sigterm)

**flutter doctor -v**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.30], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.5.1 at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ffb2ecea52 (4 days ago), 2021-09-17 15:26:33 -0400
    • Engine revision b3af521a05
    • Dart version 2.14.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.60.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.26.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • SM A205F (mobile) • 192.168.1.104:39104 • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome              • web-javascript • Google Chrome 93.0.4577.82

• No issues found!
```

**android\build.gradle file**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**android\build.properties file**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**android\app\build.gradle file**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.a"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**I tried:**

```
flutter clean

flutter upgrade

flutter pub cache repair

dart pub cache clean

delete ~/.pub-cache/hosted
```

**and I still getting the same error**

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the problem was solved**
by running
`flutter clean` in the project directory
and delete .gradle folder in C:/Users/DESKTOP-NAME/
and finally, `flutter run`